# No captura botón atrás

Tags: java, android, activity

Tengo una actividad en la que lanzo un hilo para recibir notificaciones push, lo hago en un hilo a parte para no bloquear la app. Este hilo crea un objeto tipo DataInputStream que debe permanecer abierto hasta que cierro esta actividad.

En dicha aplicación hay botones que realizan llamadas asíncronas con AsyncTask.

Si abro esta actividad y pulso el botón atrás, puedo cerrar sin problemas el DataInputStream y la actividad, que es lo que quiero.

El problema es que, si pulso uno de esos botones que realiza una llamada asíncrona, al pulsar atrás ya no me captura esa pulsación de la tecla atrás y por lo tanto, ni me cierra el DataInputStream ni la actividad.

Este es el código que utilizo para capturar la pulsación de la tecla atrás.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        try{
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

        this.finish();
        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

El problema viene al realizar una llamada asíncrona, es como si me invalidase el método onKeyDown y ya no hace nada.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el método

`onBackPressed()`: llamado exclusivamente cuando das click al boton "back" y no necesitas llamar finish() explicitamente dentro de el, esto si llamas `super.onBackPressed()` ya que internamente llama `finish()` el cual finaliza la `Activity` .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        //Si llamas super.onBackPressed(), esto internamente ejecuta finish().
        super.onBackPressed();            
}
```

Comment: No me funciona, me hace lo mismo que antes. Si realizo una llamada asíncrona desde esta actividad y pulso atrás ya no captura el método. Además veo que el botón atrás es como si se quedase pulsado, algo muy raro...

Comment: "Ya no captura el método", te refieres a que no cierra el inpustream?

Comment: a que ya no entra al método, si pongo un punto de interrupcion veo que no entra al método, creo que viene por el hilo que digo que creo para capturar las notificaciones push